# Within a column, I'd like to gsub each row of string values and remove any value that matches a list of values I created

Tags: r, string, dataframe, gsub

## Context

I am working with a messy datafile right now. I have a list of comments that I'd like to sort out and grab the most common combination of phrases. An example phrase would be "Did not qualify because of X and Y" and "Did not qualify because of Y and X". I am trying to go through and remove Stop Words so I can match X and Y as a common phrase. I was able to easily do this for common single words, but phrases are a little difficult. Below is my code for context

## Create Datafile

```
dat1 <- dat %>% filter(Action != Exclude)
```

## Remove problem characters

```
dat1$Comments <- stri_trans_general(dat1$Comments, "latin-ascii")
dat1$Comments <- gsub(pattern='<[^<>]*>', replacement=" ", x=dat1$Comments)
dat1$Comments <- gsub(pattern='\n', replacement=" ", x=dat1$Comments)
dat1$Comments <- gsub(pattern="[[:punct:]]", replacement=" ", x=dat1$Comments)
```

## Remove stop words (Where my problem is)

```
sw <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(stop_words$word, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
dat1$Comments <- lapply(dat1$Comments, function(x) (gsub(pattern=sw, replacement=" ", x)))
```

## Remove extra spaces between words

```
dat1$Comments <- trimws(gsub("\\s+", " ", dat1$Comments))
dat1$Comments <- gsub("(^[[:space:]]*)|([[:space:]]*$)", "", dat1$Comments)
```

## Sweet Data

```
top_phrases <- data.frame(text = dat1$Comments) %>%
unnest_tokens(bigram, text, 'ngrams', n = Length, to_lower = TRUE) %>% 
count(bigram, sort = TRUE)
```

## Issue

This is what pops up and is traced back to the gsub code

```
 Error in gsub(pattern = sw, replacement = " ", x) : assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634
```

If anyone is curious, here is what is stored in "sw"

```
"\\b(a|a's|able|about|above|according|accordingly|across|actually|after|afterwards|again|against|ain't|all|allow|allows|almost|alone|along|already|also|although|always|am|among|amongst|an|and|another|any|anybody|anyhow|anyone|anything|anyway|anyways|anywhere|apart|appear|appreciate|appropriate|are|aren't|around|as|aside|ask|asking|associated|at|available|away|awfully|b|be|became|because|become|becomes|becoming|been|before|beforehand|behind|being|believe|below|beside|besides|best|better|between|beyond|both|brief|but|by|c|c'mon|c's|came|can|can't|cannot|cant|cause|causes|certain|certainly|changes|clearly|co|com|come|comes|concerning|consequently|consider|considering|contain|containing|contains|corresponding|could|couldn't|course|currently|d|definitely|described|despite|did|didn't|different|do|does|doesn't|doing|don't|done|down|downwards|during|e|each|edu|eg|eight|either|else|elsewhere|enough|entirely|especially|et|etc|even|ever|every|everybody|everyone|everything|everywhere|ex|exactly|example|except|f|far|few|fifth|first|five|followed|following|follows|for|former|formerly|forth|four|from|further|furthermore|g|get|gets|getting|given|gives|go|goes|going|gone|got|gotten|greetings|h|had|hadn't|happens|hardly|has|hasn't|have|haven't|having|he|he's|hello|help|hence|her|here|here's|hereafter|hereby|herein|hereupon|hers|herself|hi|him|himself|his|hither|hopefully|how|howbeit|however|i|i'd|i'll|i'm|i've|ie|if|ignored|immediate|in|inasmuch|inc|indeed|indicate|indicated|indicates|inner|insofar|instead|into|inward|is|isn't|it|it'd|it'll|it's|its|itself|j|just|k|keep|keeps|kept|know|knows|known|l|last|lately|later|latter|latterly|least|less|lest|let|let's|like|liked|likely|little|look|looking|looks|ltd|m|mainly|many|may|maybe|me|mean|meanwhile|merely|might|more|moreover|most|mostly|much|must|my|myself|n|name|namely|nd|near|nearly|necessary|need|needs|neither|never|nevertheless|new|next|nine|no|nobody|non|none|noone|nor|normally|not|nothing|novel|now|nowhere|o|obviously|of|off|often|oh|ok|okay|old|on|once|one|ones|only|onto|or|other|others|otherwise|ought|our|ours|ourselves|out|outside|over|overall|own|p|particular|particularly|per|perhaps|placed|please|plus|possible|presumably|probably|provides|q|que|quite|qv|r|rather|rd|re|really|reasonably|regarding|regardless|regards|relatively|respectively|right|s|said|same|saw|say|saying|says|second|secondly|see|seeing|seem|seemed|seeming|seems|seen|self|selves|sensible|sent|serious|seriously|seven|several|shall|she|should|shouldn't|since|six|so|some|somebody|somehow|someone|something|sometime|sometimes|somewhat|somewhere|soon|sorry|specified|specify|specifying|still|sub|such|sup|sure|t|t's|take|taken|tell|tends|th|than|thank|thanks|thanx|that|that's|thats|the|their|theirs|them|themselves|then|thence|there|there's|thereafter|thereby|therefore|therein|theres|thereupon|these|they|they'd|they'll|they're|they've|think|third|this|thorough|thoroughly|those|though|three|through|throughout|thru|thus|to|together|too|took|toward|towards|tried|tries|truly|try|trying|twice|two|u|un|under|unfortunately|unless|unlikely|until|unto|up|upon|us|use|used|useful|uses|using|usually|uucp|v|value|various|very|via|viz|vs|w|want|wants|was|wasn't|way|we|we'd|we'll|we're|we've|welcome|well|went|were|weren't|what|what's|whatever|when|whence|whenever|where|where's|whereafter|whereas|whereby|wherein|whereupon|wherever|whether|which|while|whither|who|who's|whoever|whole|whom|whose|why|will|willing|wish|with|within|without|won't|wonder|would|would|wouldn't|x|y|yes|yet|you|you'd|you'll|you're|you've|your|yours|yourself|yourselves|z|zero|i|me|my|myself|we|our|ours|ourselves|you|your|yours|yourself|yourselves|he|him|his|himself|she|her|hers|herself|it|its|itself|they|them|their|theirs|themselves|what|which|who|whom|this|that|these|those|am|is|are|was|were|be|been|being|have|has|had|having|do|does|did|doing|would|should|could|ought|i'm|you're|he's|she's|it's|we're|they're|i've|you've|we've|they've|i'd|you'd|he'd|she'd|we'd|they'd|i'll|you'll|he'll|she'll|we'll|they'll|isn't|aren't|wasn't|weren't|hasn't|haven't|hadn't|doesn't|don't|didn't|won't|wouldn't|shan't|shouldn't|can't|cannot|couldn't|mustn't|let's|that's|who's|what's|here's|there's|when's|where's|why's|how's|a|an|the|and|but|if|or|because|as|until|while|of|at|by|for|with|about|against|between|into|through|during|before|after|above|below|to|from|up|down|in|out|on|off|over|under|again|further|then|once|here|there|when|where|why|how|all|any|both|each|few|more|most|other|some|such|no|nor|not|only|own|same|so|than|too|very|a|about|above|across|after|again|against|all|almost|alone|along|already|also|although|always|among|an|and|another|any|anybody|anyone|anything|anywhere|are|area|areas|around|as|ask|asked|asking|asks|at|away|back|backed|backing|backs|be|became|because|become|becomes|been|before|began|behind|being|beings|best|better|between|big|both|but|by|came|can|cannot|case|cases|certain|certainly|clear|clearly|come|could|did|differ|different|differently|do|does|done|down|down|downed|downing|downs|during|each|early|either|end|ended|ending|ends|enough|even|evenly|ever|every|everybody|everyone|everything|everywhere|face|faces|fact|facts|far|felt|few|find|finds|first|for|four|from|full|fully|further|furthered|furthering|furthers|gave|general|generally|get|gets|give|given|gives|go|going|good|goods|got|great|greater|greatest|group|grouped|grouping|groups|had|has|have|having|he|her|here|herself|high|high|high|higher|highest|him|himself|his|how|however|i|if|important|in|interest|interested|interesting|interests|into|is|it|its|itself|just|keep|keeps|kind|knew|know|known|knows|large|largely|last|later|latest|least|less|let|lets|like|likely|long|longer|longest|made|make|making|man|many|may|me|member|members|men|might|more|most|mostly|mr|mrs|much|must|my|myself|necessary|need|needed|needing|needs|never|new|new|newer|newest|next|no|nobody|non|noone|not|nothing|now|nowhere|number|numbers|of|off|often|old|older|oldest|on|once|one|only|open|opened|opening|opens|or|order|ordered|ordering|orders|other|others|our|out|over|part|parted|parting|parts|per|perhaps|place|places|point|pointed|pointing|points|possible|present|presented|presenting|presents|problem|problems|put|puts|quite|rather|really|right|right|room|rooms|said|same|saw|say|says|second|seconds|see|seem|seemed|seeming|seems|sees|several|shall|she|should|show|showed|showing|shows|side|sides|since|small|smaller|smallest|some|somebody|someone|something|somewhere|state|states|still|still|such|sure|take|taken|than|that|the|their|them|then|there|therefore|these|they|thing|things|think|thinks|this|those|though|thought|thoughts|three|through|thus|to|today|together|too|took|toward|turn|turned|turning|turns|two|under|until|up|upon|us|use|used|uses|very|want|wanted|wanting|wants|was|way|ways|we|well|wells|went|were|what|when|where|whether|which|while|who|whole|whose|why|will|with|within|without|work|worked|working|works|would|year|years|yet|you|young|younger|youngest|your|yours)\\b"
```

Comment: Try using `stringr`, replace `gsub(pattern=sw, replacement=" ", x)` with `stringr::str_replace_all(x, sw, " ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both TRE (the default regex engine used in base R regex functions) and PCRE (the regex engine used in base R regex functions with `perl=TRUE`) have quite hard limits for the pattern length.

In your case, `stringr` regex functions will work better as they are using ICU regex engine that supports much longer regex patterns.

So, you may replace

```r
gsub(pattern=sw, replacement=" ", x)
```

with

```r
stringr::str_replace_all(x, sw, " ")
```